# Custom font wont render for Hebrew characters using MPDF

Tags: mpdf

Fonts like ['Suez One' font](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Suez+One) and [Alef](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Alef) (and probably others too) will not render Hebrew characters 
 while generating a PDF document using MPDF library.
The rendered PDF shows the Hebrew text with the default system font. 
 **English characters placed in the same HTML div do render as 'Suez One' font correctly **

MPDF version 8.0 
PHP 7.3

Here is my code (as taken from [this](https://mpdf.github.io/fonts-languages/fonts-in-mpdf-7-x.html) example):

```
    <?php

    $defaultConfig = (new Mpdf\Config\ConfigVariables())->getDefaults();
    $fontDirs = $defaultConfig['fontDir'];
    
    $defaultFontConfig = (new Mpdf\Config\FontVariables())->getDefaults();
    $fontData = $defaultFontConfig['fontdata'];    
    
    $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf(array(
        'tempDir' => $cacheDirectory . 'tmp/',
        'format' => 'A4',
        'orientation' => 'L',
        'margin_left' => 0,
        'margin_right' =>  0,
        'margin_top' =>  0,
        'margin_bottom' =>  0,
        'margin_header' =>  0,
        'margin_footer' =>  0,
        'format'        => [208, 228],
        'fontDir' => array_merge($fontDirs, [
            dirname(__DIR__,1) . '/css/fonts',
        ]),
        'fontdata' => $fontData + [ // lowercase letters only in font key
            'suezone' => [
                'R' => 'SuezOne-Regular.ttf',
                'I' => 'SuezOne-Regular.ttf',
                'useOTL' => 0xFF,
            ]
        ],
        'default_font' => 'suezone'
    ));
    
    

    $mpdf->charset_in='UTF-8';
    $mpdf->SetDirectionality('rtl');
    $mpdf->title2annots = false;
    $mpdf->onlyCoreFonts = false;
    $mpdf->autoScriptToLang = true;
    $mpdf->autoLangToFont = true;
    $mpdf->showImageErrors = true;  
    $mpdf->allow_charset_conversion = true;

    ....
    
    $html = '<div class="shadow-box" style="font-family:suezone;text-align:center;padding:3px;width:20%;position:absolute;top:20%;right:10%;height:22mm;line-height: 150px;font-size:62pt;background-color:#ffffff;border-radius:1%"><span>טקסט בעברית - hebrew text</span></div>';

    $tmpCSS = file_get_contents( get_template_directory() . '/pdf-style.css' );         
    $mpdf->WriteHTML( $tmpCSS, \Mpdf\HTMLParserMode::HEADER_CSS );  
    $mpdf->writeHTML($html, \Mpdf\HTMLParserMode::HTML_BODY);   
    $mpdf->Output($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/pdf/pdf-file,'F');
```

CSS

```
body {
background: #fbf9c8;
font-family: 'suezone';
font-style: normal; 
font-variant: normal; 
font-weight: normal;    
}

@font-face {
    font-family:  'suezone';
    src: url('css/fonts/SuezOne-Regular.ttf');
    -fs-pdf-font-embed: embed;
    -fs-pdf-font-encoding: Identity-H;
}

@font-face {
    font-family:  'suezone';
    src: url('css/fonts/SuezOne-Regular.ttf');
}
.shadow-box {
  box-shadow: 7px 9px #383737; 
  font-family: 'suezone';
}
```

This font renders OK in HTML for me.
I tried to add @font-face, looked through various solutions. nothing works so far.

After investigating further, i noticed the addfont() function in src/Mpdf.php
runs multiple times and sometimes is outputting the system font instead of the newly defined default_font.

So i changed the $unifont value in

vendor/mpdf/mpdf/src/Language/LanguageToFont.php

to my custom font name:

`case 'he': case 'heb': // HEBREW case 'yi': case 'yid': // Yiddish $unifont = 'suezone'; // dejavusans,dejavusanscondensed,freeserif are fine if you do not need cantillation marks break;`

and it solved the problem.
but this is not sustainable and is just a temporary workaround.

Thank you for your help.